# Get the query log which fetch more than 10000 rec in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In my application some of the MySQL select query returns more than 10000 due to that getting memory issue, but that same query works faster due to that not logging in slow query log.

Please help me to find that query.

Comment: Turn on the general query log? Be advised that this is a firehose of every query and might exhaust your disk space quickly if left on.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I hope general query log will log all the queries which is executing, How to get the appropriate query?

Comment: It logs every single query, so you just have to go looking. Since I've got no idea what your query looks like, that's something you'll have to figure out. Remember, if you're looking for cases of rampant memory use you'll want to search for queries with no `LIMIT` clause.